# How to save id and use it correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to save the id of the article i clicked on and to use it to change its css rules with this.id.
With a known id it worked but when i try to change my function for it to work with every article it doesn't work anymore.

This is for a project in my school, also sorry if the question was already answered but i'm new to js and jquery so i didn't know why it didn't work for me.

```
<section id="shop">
            <article class='savons' id="test">
                <img src="../css/images/savons/1,6 euros/1 violette.jpg" alt="savon violette" id="photo">
                <div class='info' id="info">
                    <h6>savon de marseille 50g </h6>
                    <p class='prix'>2,90€</p>
                    <p class='zoom'><a href="#">voir</a></p>
                </div>
            </article>

            <article class='savons' id="test1">
                <img src="../css/images/savons/1,6 euros/2 porquerolle.jpg" alt="savon porquerolle">
                <div class='info'>
                    <h6>savon détachant exfoliant 100g</h6>
                    <p class='prix'>3,75€</p>
                    <p class='zoom'><a href="#">voir</a></p>
                </div>
            </article>

            <article class='savons' id="test2">
                <img src="../css/images/savons/1,6 euros/3 marine.jpg" alt="savon marine ">
                <div class='info'>
                    <h6>savon de marseille 100g</h6>
                    <p class='prix'>3,25€</p>
                    <p class='zoom'><a href="#">voir</a></p>
                </div>
            </article>
</section>


$(document).ready(function () {
$('.savons').click(function(){
    let id=$(this).attr('id');
    $("id").css({
        color : 'red', // couleur rouge
        width : '1500px', 
        height : '500px', 
        marginLeft:'150px',
        marginRight:'50px',
        border:'solid'
    });
    $("#photo").css({
       width : '350px', 
       height : '350px'
    });
    $("#info").css({
       width : '350px', 
       height : '350px'
    });
    $("article").not(document.getElementById("id")).css({
       filter:"blur(10px)"
    });
});
});
```

with the real id "test" it works but with "id" it doesn't, and i don't know why, i probably don't use this.id correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You must put the variable id with the # selector.

```
let id=$(this).attr('id'); 
$("#"+id).css({
```

Answer (score 1):

`$("#id")` will look for an element with an ID of "id".  If you have the ID in a variable named "id", you want `$('#' + id)`.  (The '#' is what identifies it as an ID in the selector, and you want the variable name unquoted to get its value, instead of the literal string 'id'.)

In this case, however, you already have a reference to the element you care about in `this`, so you don't need to use the ID at all:

```
$(this).css({
        color : 'red', // couleur rouge
        width : '1500px', 
        height : '500px', 
        marginLeft:'150px',
        marginRight:'50px',
        border:'solid'
    });
```

Similarly, later in your code, you can use `not($(this))` instead of the vanilla DOM method `getElementById` you're currently using. (Though if you do keep using the ID, the variable name should be unquoted there too: `getElementById(id)`, not `getElementById("id")`.)

(It's generally considered better to not switch back and forth indiscriminately between equivalent jQuery and vanilla methods -- it works fine to mix them, it's just more confusing to debug than if you pick one style and stick to it.)

Answer (score 0):

in your case you could use

```
$(this).css({
```

to change the css of the clicked item

If you want to use Ids

```
$("#"+id).css({
```